# Send basa64 string to webService

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, database

What is best way to send data from html to webService? My base64 string is very long (5000 character and more).

I'm use ajax but not working for very long string.

Any solution?

Comment: maybe a special design pattern, like send chunks... start and end.. so it knows when its complete... then do something.. if x time passes then kill it... by rejecting it. only saying all this as you said webService... interesting question tho.

Comment: I'm sure that someone else would of run into this exact some problem. And im sure that some how they would be streaming the data into some kind of service, but how you get this out of web services out the box? like a said i would also be interested.

Comment: @Seabizkit Tnx for answer but I don't understand your solution!

Comment: have a look at something like http://www.seesharpdot.net/?p=214